# Visual Studio 2010: Use hardware graphics acceleration if available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide, hardware-acceleration, video-card

My Via/S3G UniChrome Pro IGP does not support hardware acceleration in Visual Studio 2010. What kind of graphic cards (i.e. the specific features) do support this hardware acceleration?

Comment: VS2010 is a WPF 4.0 application. Probably requires Shader Model 2 or 3.

Comment: @Dee: It is a hardware question, really.  None of this involves your code in any way that I can see, and you're asking about hardware, so I'm voting to migrate to superuser.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, this is a hardware question that only programmers with visual studio 2010 experiences can answer. I think I have higher chances to get answer here than other places. Please consider your move, please.

Comment: @Dee Jay: Hardly. Many power users are familiar with which hardware and drivers are compatible with DirectWrite/Direct2D. More to the point, SO isn't a site for asking programmers questions. It's a site for asking questions about programming. Lots of programmers answer hardware questions on SU and EE, or web service questions on WM, or security questions on SF.

Comment: @Dee Jay: Agree with @Ben. It's in no way a programmING question, although it might be a programmER question (in which case it should be going to P.SE, although that's probably not a good idea).

Comment: Retagged, as this has nothing to do with C# or VB.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On XP, with VS2010 SP1 you need to override a setting to get HW acceleration.  See here for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/03/03/performance-troubleshooting-article-and-vs2010-sp1-change.aspx

Beyond that, VS2010 is subject to the requirements of WPF HW acceleration.  For those, see the table on this page which explains what WPF needs to have a system considered "Tier 1" or "Tier 2" - there are multiple factors.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx

Answer (score 3):

According to the [VS.Net 2010 site](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/premium/overview), you need a "DirectX 9 capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher-resolution display".

There does seems to be a general lack of information as to exactly what cards will give you the accelerated functionality, tho'.

Comment: @Will A: What is your video card? Does it support hardware acceleration? Please share with us.

Comment: @David - I'm getting hardware acceleration and am using a (several years old) nVidia GeForce 7600GT w/ 2GB graphics memory.  Perhaps more importantly I'm running on Windows 7 (less importantly, x64) - I know VS.Net 2010 runs like a dog on XP.

Comment: VS2010 SP1 also turns off acceleration on Windows XP, even if you have the hardware for it. You can turn it back on, though. The point though, is if you have XP, you may not even want acceleration on.

Comment: @vcsjones: Care to elaborate why hardware acceleration for XP is bad idea?

Comment: @Gens I'd assume that if the Visual Studio team think's it is not worth having on by default, then something is wrong with it on XP, at least for a significant number of developers.

Comment: @Gens "A significant number of crash reports stemming from hardware acceleration"

Comment: @vcsjones I've been using hardware acceleration on XP with my laptop's NVIDIA Quadro FX 350M for many months now, no crashes.